# How to change the width of a position:fixed element

Tags: css

I have window size 1000px;
I have a div on left which have width of 700px(it is fix) , and i have a div on right which have  position is fixed, and its initial width is 300px;

```
<div id="right" style="position:fixed;max-width:300px; />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t2w25xbj/

Try  resizing window on this jsfiddle

Now what i really want is when i resize the browser window,  right  div  should not overlap to the left size div and should changes its width according to the space left in the right side .  Just like any inline-block element,

Is their any way to do this?

Comment: Use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: `width:calc(100% - 700px)` is the solution of this question . https://jsfiddle.net/t2w25xbj/9/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position:static` and `floats` instead of fixed positioning.

This should work:

```css
#left {
    position:static;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
}

#right {
    background:yellow;
    position:static;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
    min-width:200px;
}
```

Also, you forgot to close the second div.

I think that it would have been much easier if you used bootstrap.

Comment: Athough float and position fixed can not give same effects(because fixed elements has no effect on scrolling the page ), But i got an idea from ur answer , I can set width of the right side div `style="width:calc(100%-700px);`

Comment: i don't why this property  is not working in js fiddle, May be this property `calc` in supported in all browsers

Comment: @beginner You actually have to put spaces in between `code`100% - 700px`code`

Answer (score 0):

```css
#left{
  height:150px;
  background:green;
  width:auto;
  margin-right:150px;
}
#right{background:yellow;
  position:fixed;
  height:150px;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:150px}
}

body,html{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="left">

</div>
<div id="right" />
This is div with position fixed it, should change its width according to the space left in right size when i resize the window
```

have a look link also https://jsfiddle.net/t2w25xbj/6/

Comment: i want to change the width of right div , width of left div should be fix

Comment: Please note that zero-lengths should omit the unit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#left{
  width:30%;
  max-width: 700px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  float: left;
}
#right{background:yellow;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width: 65%;
  min-width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

in html,

add this `<div class="clear"></div>` as a sibling of right, left div elements